# How do I know if a symbolic link in Windows still works?

Tags: windows, symbolic-link, junction, mklink, links

I have lots of symbolic links (Windows 7). How do I know if they are working or if they are dead (that is, the original file has been deleted/moved/renamed)?

I tried

```
if not exist mylink.txt echo The link is dead
```

But this doesn't work: if the link exist, `if exist` always answer `true` regardless if the link is dead or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use fsutil to check if both the symbolic link file and the linked file exist.

```
fsutil file queryfileid mylink.txt
if errorlevel 1 echo The link is dead
```

If you want to check all symbolic links in a folder, you can use

```
FOR %%f IN (*) DO (
  fsutil file queryfileid %%f
  if errorlevel 1 echo The link is dead
)
```

But you should take care. fsutil might also exit with exit code 1 if an error occurs.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a quick solution for deleting all symbolic links that are dead in a folder?
I imagine it is possible with your `fsutil`, but I don't know how to make such a loop...

Comment: @JosBas I added a for loop to my answer. You can use that to walk through all files in a folder. But you should take care, fsutil might exit with exit code 1 not only for dead links, but also when other errors occur. You should echo the file names first before running a bat file which deletes the files (replace the echo with a `del %%f`)!